# Running composer without using sudo

Tags: composer-php, root, sudo

I've followed the guide on installing composer globally from the composer site: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

The problem is I have to use sudo every time I use composer. This is a pain as every vendor folder that's created with `sudo composer update` is under the owner of `root` which I have to change to `www-data`.

**Things I've tried:**

I've tried using `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer` which still requires me to run composer with sudo as the file is owned by `root`.

Changing owner of `/usr/local/bin/composer` to `www-data:www-data` with privileges set to 775. Still requires me to run composer with sudo prepended first.

**How can I resolve this so I do not have to use `sudo` every time I run composer?**

Answer (score 7):

Figured out the problem.

1) I either had to clear out the cache in `/home/lamp/.composer` or change the owner of this

2) And change the owner of `/usr/local/bin/composer`

After doing these 2 changes I can now run composer commands without using `sudo`.

Comment: There should be no reason to change the owner of `/usr/local/bin/composer`. Even if the file is owned by `root`, the environment upon execution is the one of the user running it.