# How can I install AWS SDK for PHP in Wordpress without installing a Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I need to use AWS SDK for PHP in Wordpress, but the available plugins are either dated or not-free, how can I install the latest SDK in my Wordpress implementation?

Comment: Can you share me the paid plugin which would help me integrating AWS SDK to  wordpress site

Answer (score 2):

To install the SDK in a Wordpress server I followed the following steps:

1) Install the SDK using Composer, using the official AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html). I installed in in the /var/www/html folder. Please note that it's no advisable to run composer using sudo, so I followed the following recommendations: [Running composer without using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111615/running-composer-without-using-sudo).

2) Make sure that the vendor folder is at the same level as the wp-config.php.

3) Add the include in the file you need it:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: What if you want to install it into your wordpress installation and not make it available to the whole server?  Put in in a wp-content/vendor folder?